# Error 1723 while uninstalling Java

Tags: java

I've installed java 1.6u33 on my Windows 7 machine. Everything was fine, I was running Eclipse for example. But I did a mistake - I deleted the jre6 dir. Now I am trying to reinstall Java with no success.

I got this msg when I try to uninstall it:

> error 1723 there is a problem with this Windows installer package a dll required for this install to complete could not be run.

I've deleted everything I had found for java in the registry,the Java dir, also tried JavaRa. I saw in MSI****.LOG files what dll is missing and put it where it was searched for. No success. So is there a way I can reinstall java without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: what dll file was that?